# Zygote shared libraries handling

Tags: android, process

How zygote handles the shared libraries in android?
Zygote is a special process in Android which handles the forking of each new application process. These processes are simply regular Linux processes. We may think of the Zygote as the template process for each app and service that is started on the device. It is launched by the Android runtime, which also starts the first Virtual Machine (VM). The VM then calls Zygote’s main() method which causes Zygote to preload all shared Java classes and resource into memory. How it work with shaed library?

Answer (score 1):

There was one time I had an issue with the shared library compilation, and the application crashed with below trace log:

```
backtrace:
#00 pc 00000000001938f8  /data/app/com.xxxxx.test-1/lib/arm64/libmyNative.so
#01 pc 0000000000002300  /system/bin/linker64 (__dl__ZN6soinfo12CallFunctionEPKcPFvvE.part.22+80)
#02 pc 000000000000294c  /system/bin/linker64 (__dl__ZN6soinfo9CallArrayEPKcPPFvvEmb+232)
#03 pc 0000000000005200  /system/bin/linker64 (__dl__Z9do_dlopenPKciPK17android_dlextinfo+264)
#04 pc 0000000000001cbc  /system/bin/linker64 (__dl__ZL10dlopen_extPKciPK17android_dlextinfo+48)
#05 pc 0000000000284bc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+824)
#06 pc 00000000002c2e2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+700)
#07 pc 00000000000b9528  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat
```

From the log, we can understand how this libmyNative.so is being loaded at first time.
1. boot.oat is not only responsible of loading android framework and resources, it's also responsible to load application shared library.
2. boot.oat is a Java library, it will call to native libart.so to load native libraries, Runtime_nativeLoad() -> LoadNativeLibrary().
3. For the following steps, if you hooked native library before, or you dynamically linked native library from android application by yourself before, you will have better understanding. One example of linking shared library by yourself instead of calling System.loadLibrary():

```
void* lib = dlopen("/data/app/com.xxxxx.test-1/lib/arm64/libmyNative.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void* func_ptr = (void*)dlsym(* lib, "JNI_Onload");
```

So inside LoadNativeLibrary(), it does the similar thing. You can check the implementation of LoadNativeLibrary() from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/d000480/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc#575).

4. During the native library loading, some parts of init code is executed also. If you know .so file structure, you will know there is a .init_array section including some init functions added by the compiler and the global constructors you declare explicitly in your code. The crash I have is inside one of the init function added by the compiler.
5. One thing I have doubt is inside the LoadNativeLibrary(), it seems to call `JNI_Onload()`, but from what I observer, it doesn't. Because I tried to let `JNI_Onload()` return -1 directly, it is not thrown error message from there, instead it throws the error message when I call System.loadLibrary(). This is expected.

> 03-08 18:10:12.311 14797-14797/com.xxxxx.test E/JNI_OnLoad: System.loadLibrary(myNative)
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.xxxxx.test-2/lib/arm64/libmyNative.so"
>      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
>      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
>      at com.gemalto.tee.taadmin.TaAdmin.init(TaAdmin.java:86)